# How to add toggle button in WordPress plugin settings?

Tags: wordpress

I can add text input and button to settings page like this:

```
 echo '<textarea type="text" id="inputs" name="inputs" style="width:60%;">' . esc_attr(get_option('custom_plugin_options')) . '</textarea>';
                    echo '</p>';
                    echo '<p class="submit">';
                    echo '<input class="button-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />';
                    echo '</p>';
```

But I'm unsure about adding toggle button to WordPress plugin settings. I have several questions in mind. I'm thinking if the right way to do it is add a checkbox and apply css that will make the checkbox as toggle button and add it like adding the text input. Is it the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, toggle button is just an `styled` checkbox so you can return a input element with `checkbox` in `type` attribute. Here's my code using in my plugins:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="your_plugin_option_name" value="1" ' . checked( 1, get_option( 'your_plugin_option_name' ), false ) . ' />';
```

Comment: quick question, will this save the option automatically or what other configurations I'll have to make?

Comment: The answer is yes, if you registered `your_plugin_option_name` by `register_setting()`.